# What's the difference between QQuickView and QQuickWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am currently working with Qt 5.2.1... and I have a (maybe stupid?) question: What is the difference between `QQuickView` and `QQuickWindow`?

I read the documentation but it is still not clear to me...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the Qt documentation:

> The QQuickView class provides a window for displaying a Qt Quick user
>   interface.
>
> QQuickView is a convenience subclass of QQuickWindow which will
>   automatically load and display a QML scene when given the URL of the
>   main source file.

So QQuickView is a subclass of QQuickWindow which manages displaying a scene from a QML file and could be used easily like:

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqmlfile.qml"));
view->show();
```

For displaying a graphical QML scene in a window you can also use the QQuickWindow class.

Also from the Qt documentation:

> A QQuickWindow always has a single invisible root item. To add items
>   to this window, reparent the items to the root item or to an existing
>   item in the scene.

So it can be used like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl("myqmlfile.qml"));

QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

window->show();
```