# Dynamically load QQuickWindow instead of QQuickWidget in Qt C++ unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qml, qt5, qqmlengine

In our project we have C++ unit tests for QML sources. It uses following code to load component dynamically for further processing

```
class MyTest {
    ...
    QScopedPointer<QQuickWidget> quickWidget;
    QQuickItem* root = nullptr;

    void setQmlSource(const QString& source)
    {
        quickWidget.reset(new QQuickWidget);
        quickWidget->rootContext()->engine()->addImportPath("qrc:/qml");
        quickWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromUserInput(source));
        root = quickWidget->rootObject();
    }
}
```

Worked fine for qml components like this:

**my.qml:**

```
Rectangle {
   ...
}
```

However when I wrapped component into `Dialog`

```
Dialog {
    ...
    Rectangle {
       ...
    }
}
```

it stopped to work:

> **Error:** `QQuickWidget` only supports loading of root objects that derive from `QQuickItem`.

Which is expected as `Dialog` is a `QQuickWindow`. However trying to load `QQuickItem` via `QQuickView` like this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html#details:

```
void MyTest::setQmlWindow(const QString& source)
{
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->rootContext()->engine()->addImportPath("qrc:/qml");
    view->setSource(QUrl::fromUserInput(source));
    root = view->rootObject();
}
```

Fails with above error as well. And loading via `QQmlApplicationEngine` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936741/630169:

```
void MyTest::setQmlWindow(const QString& source)
{
    engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine;
    //engine->addImportPath("qrc:/qml");
    engine->load(QUrl::fromUserInput(source));
    QObject *myObject = engine->rootObjects().first();;
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(myObject);
    root = window->contentItem();
}
```

fails with another error:

> `QQmlApplicationEngine` failed to load component
>   QWARN  : `MyTest::myMethodTest()` module "`mynamespace.mymodule`" is not installed
>   QWARN  : `MyTest::myMethodTest()` module "`mynamespace.mymodule`" is not installed
>   ...

Why `view->setSource()` loads this modules correctly for `Rectangle` item and `QQmlApplicationEngine` fails to do for the same item qml source but wrapped into  the `Dialog`?

> **Note:** these modules are C++ and loads fine with `view->setSource()`.

If I try to use and load via `QQmlComponent` like mentioned in documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#details:

```
void MyTest::setQmlWindow(const QString& source)
{
    engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine;
    //engine->addImportPath("qrc:/qml");
    QQmlComponent *component = new QQmlComponent(engine, QUrl::fromUserInput(source));
    component->loadUrl(QUrl::fromUserInput(source));
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(component->create());
    root = window->contentItem();
}
```

- then have another error:

  > `QQmlComponent`: Component is not ready

if `engine->addImportPath()` is not called, and crash with

> Loc: [Unknown file(0)]

error when `engine->addImportPath()` is called.

How to correctly load `Dialog` (`QQuickWindow`) and get it root `QQuickItem` in C++ for testing? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your question is about `QQuickWindow`/`QQuickView`? How does `QQuickWidget` related to the issue? That just a wrapper for `QQuickWindow`. Anyway, I would use some QML dynamic loading wrapper instead. The idea is to load each component sequentially. The example below just illustrates the idea. If you don't need a functional testing just remove timers and Connections and play with `Loader.Ready` instead.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test window")
    property var objects: ["Item1.qml", "Item2.qml", "Item3.qml"]
    property int currentObject: 0
    property var testResults: [0, 0]
    property bool testRunning: false

    onTestRunningChanged: {
        if(window.testRunning)
            console.log("start testing");
        else
            console.log("all the objects has tested. passed: " + window.testResults[0] + ", failed: " + window.testResults[1]);
    }

    function loadObject() {
        try
        {
            loader.source = window.objects[window.currentObject];
        }
        catch(ex) {}
    }

    function checkNext(prevStatus) {
        if(!window.testRunning)
            return;

        window.testResults[prevStatus ? 0 : 1]++;
        timer.running  = false;
        console.log(window.objects[window.currentObject] + ":" + ((prevStatus) ? "passed" : "failed"))
        if(window.currentObject === window.objects.length - 1) {
            window.testRunning = false;
        } else {
            window.currentObject ++;
            loadObject();
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onStatusChanged: {
            if (loader.status == Loader.Error) {
                loader.source = "";
                checkNext(false);
            }
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: loader.item
        onTestPassed: checkNext(true);
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 5000
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: checkNext(false);
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        window.testRunning = true;
        loadObject();
    }
}
```

**Item1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Dialog {
    id: item
    signal testPassed(bool value);
    title: "Dialog test"
    modal: true
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
    visible: true
    onAccepted: item.testPassed(true);
}
```

**Item2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Rectangle {
    id: item
    signal testPassed(bool value);

    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "orange"

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Test"
        onClicked: item.testPassed(true);
    }
}
```

Item3.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    Itemssss {

    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to create an object in C++, in unit test, not in QML.

Comment: Why exactly in C++? I mean you should avoid creating QML components in C++ as much as possible. Anyway, in the same way you can use `QQmlComponent` instead.

Comment: Please read my initial question: I need unit test, so loading QML components there. As well as QML application initialized and loaded in that way as well - via `QQmlApplicationEngine` in C++ ;)

Comment: About `QQmlComponent` - tried with same result and error: ```QQmlComponent: Component is not ready``` if `addImportPath()` is not called, and crash with `Loc: [Unknown file(0)]` error when called.

Comment: Ok, you cannot load `Dialog` as a root item, the error message is  is quite clear. Both `QQuickWidget` and `QQuickWindow` require the root item will be the `QQuickItem` descendant. Using `QQmlComponent` won't help of course. You can try to use ` QQuickWindow` instead of `QQuickWidget`

Comment: Of course I use `QQuickWindow` however it could be loaded only via `QQmlComponent`: `component = new QQmlComponent(&engine);
    component->loadUrl(url);` No luck as well - see the question, I've just updated it.

Comment: Loading a component using `QQmlComponent::loadUrl` is an asynchronous operation by default. You should either set `QQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous` or relay on `statusChanged` and create a component when it is `QQmlComponent::Ready`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, probably. However solved for now by removing `Dialog` (reverted changes) and using `quickWidget->setSource()` again which works.